# User input date validation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a text box and would like to ensure dates are entered in the format YYYYMMDD. The below stops any other characters then numerical being entered. My Javascript is faily rusty, how can i ensure that the text entered into the textbox also starts with "202"

```js
function chkNum(event, msg) {
    if (!(event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57)) {
        document.getElementById(msg).innerHTML = "Invalid date format";
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById(msg).innerHTML = "";
        return true;
    }
}
```

```html
<input name="remdel<%=orderno%>" type="number" min="0" step="1" id="remdel<%=orderno%>" value="" size="10" onkeypress="return chkNum(event,'error')"
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith ?

Comment: Make sure you handle the case where the input is less than 3 characters, otherwise they won't be able to start typing the date.

Comment: Why don't you just set `min="20200101"`?

Comment: But you probably shouldn't use `type="number"` for a date. Why don't you use a datepicker?

Comment: Changed top line to if(!(event.which>=48 && event.which<=57 && msg.startsWith='202')) which doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Why not use regex expressions.
there is so much resources available and lots of fancy ways here on SO.

here is a basic non production guide according to your requirements:
it needs some work and i have separated the regex to provide clarity...
You can also add checks to make sure the 5th and 6th digits are between 1-12 and that the 7th and 8th digits are not greater than 31, just to make it a little more fool proof.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head
   <body>
       <input id="txtDate" type="text" />
       <span id="lblResult"></span>

       <script type="text/javascript">
           function Validatekey(e) {
     
           // Get the key that was pressed.
           // Add the key pressed to our input because it technically isnt there until after this method completes
           var dtValue = document.getElementById("txtDate").value + e.key;
     
           // Check that user pressed a number ie. 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           if (!new RegExp("^[0-9]+$").test(dtValue)) {
               // Regect if not a number then reject.
               e.preventDefault();
           }
     
           // Check for 8 digits
           if (!new RegExp(/^[0-9]{1,8}$/).test(dtValue)) {
               // Regect if not a number then reject.
               e.preventDefault();
           }
     
           // Check if starts with 202 and the rest of the number
           if (!new RegExp(/^(202)([0-9]{5})$/).test(dtValue)) {
               document.getElementById("lblResult").innerHTML = false;  
           }else{ document.getElementById("lblResult").innerHTML = true;  }
     
           }
           // Attach event handler to our input
          document.getElementById("txtDate").addEventListener("keypress", Validatekey);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```